# String replacement without handycap

Tags: c#, regex

I got a problem about string replacement, because of substrings chancing somewhere. For example

```
component1 = 5;
component2 = 6;
component10= 7;
```

when I want to replace component1 with **variable**, component10 will change as **variable0**

How should I prevent this in C#

Comment: What? Are these 3 different strings? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use non word boundary.So,your regex would be

```
\bcomponent1\b
```

This would match component1 as a separate word and not as a substring

---

your code would be

```
string output=Regex.Replace(input,@"\bcomponent1\b");
```

`@` is required else `\b` would be treated as special character which would give you error because `\b` is not a valid escape character or use `\\b`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace them in descending order of substring length.